# Excel macro - ignore column headers?

Tags: excel, sorting, header

I have an Excel Macro as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i&, j&, k&, LR_A&, LR_B&, LR_C&, count&

LR_A = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
LR_B = Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
LR_C = Range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
count = 1

For i = 1 To LR_A
  For j = 1 To LR_B
     For k = 1 To LR_C
        Range("D" & count).Value = Range("A" & i).Value
        Range("E" & count).Value = Range("B" & j).Value
        Range("F" & count).Value = Range("C" & k).Value
        count = count + 1
     Next k
  Next j
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

As you can see, it is resorting the data in columns A, B, and C into D, E, and F.

What code do I need to add to get it to ignore the column headers in A, B, and C? I have searched around but have been unable to find an answer.

In addition, how would I change it so that it instead of resorting the data into D, E, and F, it is resorting it into A, B, and C on another worksheet?

This is my first macro, so they are pretty basic questions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to your question**

To avoid copying the headers, you should begin your loops at index `2`.
To copy values to another `Worksheet`, you need to call it in your `Range`.

```
For i = 2 To LR_A
  For j = 2 To LR_B
     For k = 2 To LR_C
        Sheets("My other ws").Range("D" & count).Value = Range("A" & i).Value
        Sheets("My other ws").Range("E" & count).Value = Range("B" & j).Value
        Sheets("My other ws").Range("F" & count).Value = Range("C" & k).Value
        count = count + 1
     Next k
  Next j
Next i
```

**Maybe a better way to handle this case**

Looping over range using index can be very slow.
I advise you to have a look at this link: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/VBALoops.htm where the author explained faster ways to loop over ranges.

**Some tips**

Have a look at Excel `SpecialCells` as described [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/special-cells.htm).
For instance, in your case, you could try to use `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` instead of finding the last used row.

Comment: I'll look into those other methods, but your suggestions for the Macro didn't work at all. When I put in the worksheet stuff into the range, Excel suddenly gives me the error "Compile error: Function or sub not defined." And even if I take that out and just have i, j, and k set to 2, the macro just won't run anymore.

Comment: @Billy: sorry, i edited my code. i made a mistake on the `Sheets` syntax

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks a lot! Also, thanks for the links to the other stuff, I am going to use that, too.